# When I run a WPF application using the Surface 2.0 SDK, no surface controls show up

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

So I have a simple C#/WPF 4.0 application that includes several SurfaceTextBox instances. When I debug the app in Visual Studio everything looks fine and the Surface controls load as expected.

When I run the app on a separate Windows 7 Tablet device, all of the Surface-specific controls do not load, and they look as if their visibility property is set to hidden.

The Surface dll references I added are Microsoft.Surface.Core and Microsoft.Surface.Presentation. Do I need other references as well?

The SDK version I'm using http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the Win7 tablet has the [Surface Runtime](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/E/44E7A6B8-7F51-4B1B-A5FF-B02E4C8F2BA7/SurfaceRuntime.msi) installed.